# Can't seem to calculate a matrice with for loop

Tags: python

I have an assignment where i need to rewrite a matlab program with python, the purpose of this program is to find the amptitude of an object. I been trying to find the array y but i always get
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50,9) into shape (50,), i don't know if i get this error because the way i defind y, or there is something else missing.I get the error in the last line

`````
x = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
z = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
o = np.array([[0,0,2],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]])
flattenmatrixO = np.array(o).flatten('F')
N = len(flattenmatrixO)

xt = np.array([1,2,3])
zt = 0
L = len(xt)
K = 50
fs, Dt, c = 10, 1/10, 15e-1
y = np.zeros([K,N])

for i in range(0,L):
    tof = ((z-zt) + np.sqrt((x-xt[i])**2 + (z-zt)**2))/c
    kd = np.round(tof/Dt)
    kd = kd.astype(int)
    kd = np.array(kd).flatten(order='F')
    
    Hl = np.zeros([K,N])
    for n in range(0,N):
        Hl[kd[n],n] = 1
    H = [H,Hl]
    O = np.array(o).flatten(order='F')
    y[:,i] = Hl * O````   

#for refrence the last line in matlab is written like this:
#y(:,i) = Hl * o(:)
`````

Comment: The shape of y is (50,9), the shape of y[:, i] is (50,) and the shape of Hl * O is also (50,9). So if you wanna assign Hl*O to y[:, i] the dimensions don't match. But that's already in your error message.

How y defined in the matlab script?

Comment: y is defined y = zeros(K,N)

Comment: Please read the tag description of tags before spamming them. This has nothing to do with MATLAB and [tag:python-3.x] says: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag. "

Comment: So if both the shape of `y` and `Hl` is KxN, the last line cannot work, as you basically get rid of N by indexing into it and then try to place KxN into K elements. Sharing the original section of the matlab code might help.